# Saving a dataset of rows in hbase

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-kafka, hbase, spark-streaming

I am reading data(json string) from Kafka, parsing it to convert to a dataset with a given schema and performing aggregations over an attribute for that data set. I want to store this data set in hbase after converting it into a json string. What is the best way to do this?
sample dataset:

```
id|name|age

1 |geet|21
```

expected output against my key in hbase:

```
{"id":"1","name":"geet","age":"21"}
```

Comment: Why are you storing json in Hbase?

Answer (score 2):

Spark doesn't provide a sink for HBASE. You can try [spark-hbase](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc) connector provided by Hortonworks. Else you could loop over the RDD/DF/DS like below,

```
hbaseout.forEachPartition { record =>
record.ForEach {
//hbase write code goes here
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to do this?

please note that [Hbase connector](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc) available only if you are using on Hortonworks distribution.

I am giving general example (other than your json)

Follow the below [example of SparkOnHbase](https://github.com/tmalaska/SparkOnHBase/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/spark/example/rdd/HBaseForeachPartitionExample.scala) code with `foreachPartition` to store json in to hbase in your desired format..

```
package org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.example.rdd

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{TableName, HBaseConfiguration}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseContext
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseRDDFunctions._
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
/**
* This is a simple example of using the foreachPartition
* method with a HBase connection
*/
object HBaseForeachPartitionExample {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
if (args.length < 2) {
println("HBaseBulkPutExample {tableName} {columnFamily}")
return
}
val tableName = args(0)
val columnFamily = args(1)
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HBaseBulkPutExample " +
tableName + " " + columnFamily)
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
try {
//[(Array[Byte], Array[(Array[Byte], Array[Byte], Array[Byte])])]
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(
(Bytes.toBytes("1"),
Array((Bytes.toBytes(columnFamily), Bytes.toBytes("1"), Bytes.toBytes("1")))),
(Bytes.toBytes("2"),
Array((Bytes.toBytes(columnFamily), Bytes.toBytes("1"), Bytes.toBytes("2")))),
(Bytes.toBytes("3"),
Array((Bytes.toBytes(columnFamily), Bytes.toBytes("1"), Bytes.toBytes("3")))),
(Bytes.toBytes("4"),
Array((Bytes.toBytes(columnFamily), Bytes.toBytes("1"), Bytes.toBytes("4")))),
(Bytes.toBytes("5"),
Array((Bytes.toBytes(columnFamily), Bytes.toBytes("1"), Bytes.toBytes("5"))))
))
val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
val hbaseContext = new HBaseContext(sc, conf)
rdd.hbaseForeachPartition(hbaseContext,
(it, connection) => {
  val m = connection.getBufferedMutator(TableName.valueOf(tableName))
  it.foreach(r => {
  val put = new Put(r._1)
  r._2.foreach((putValue) =>
  put.addColumn(putValue._1, putValue._2, putValue._3))
  m.mutate(put)
})
  m.flush()
  m.close()
})
} finally {
  sc.stop()
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write resulting data back into another Kafka topic and then use the Cassandra Kafka Connector available at https://github.com/landoop/stream-reactor to write that data into Cassandra